# Summation of a trigonometric series involving $\arctan x$

Tags: trigonometry, power-series

The original question was to find $y$ if $x \in (0,1)$, $y \in (\pi/4,\pi/2)$ and $$\arctan{(x+h)} = \arctan{x} + h\sin^2y - h\frac{\sin^2y\sin2y}{2} + h\frac{\sin^3y\sin3y}{3} - ...$$ I moved $\arctan{x}$ on to the LHS, divided by $h$ and took $\lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0}$ on both sides and got $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \sin^2y - \frac{\sin^2y\sin2y}{2} + \frac{\sin^3y\sin3y}{3} - ...$$ Now can we find $y$ in terms of $x$ and $h$?

Will this approach work or is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: What kind of series are you looking for ? A fourier series ?

Comment: @Peter I want to write $y$ as a function of $x$ and $h$.

Comment: Your limit is meaningless as $h$ appears nowhere.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $y$ may be dependent on $h$. Hence the limit is not meaningless.

Comment: I have just mentioned an approach to the original problem that I tried. That approach may not be correct and I would be glad to find out why.

Comment: The next term in the series is $\ -h\frac{(sin^4y)(sin(4y))}{4}\ $ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes. With a negative sign.

Comment: @Iguana: I know, but this is only apparent when you read what follows.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I will rephrase the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your approach would only solve the case $h\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\sin^ky\sin ky=\Im\left(\sin^ky\,e^{iky}\right)$$ so that the series yields

$$\Im\left(\ln\left(1+\sin y\,e^{iy}\right)\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\sin^2y}{1+\sin y\cos y}\right).$$

---

Then

$$\frac{\sin^2y}{1+\sin y\cos y}=\tan\left(\frac{\arctan(x+h)-\arctan x}{h}\right)=:t,$$ which can be solved for $y$.

You can rewrite as

$$2-\cos(2y)=t(2+\sin(2y))$$ to get a linear trigonometric equation that has a well-know solution. The expression of $t$ des not simplify.